# attempting to combine (mutate) two rows into a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to mutate a column by dividing the value of a row with the value above. For example, lets say i have this dataframe:

```
  V1
A 4
B 2
C 8
```

Using something like:

`df <- mutate(df, V2 = V1[row+1] / V1[row])`

I want to get:

```
  V1  v2
A 4   NA
B 2   2
C 8   0.25
```

I can't find any way to do this...does anyone have any info?

edit: clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- mutate(df, v2 = lag(V1) / V1)
```

Output:

```
  V1   v2
A  4   NA
B  2 2.00
C  8 0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can remove the first and last element and do the division

```
df$V2 <-  with(df,  c(NA, V1[-length(V1)]/V1[-1]))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(4, 2, 8)), class = "data.frame", 
   row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C"))
```